# How do I add another project's build artifacts into a .war using gradle?

Tags: war, gradle

Related to [How do I add a .properties file into my WAR using gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683375/how-do-i-add-a-properties-file-into-my-war-using-gradle) but not quite:

I've got one project, call it 'webclient' that produces:

```
build/out/WEB-INF/deploy/foo
build/out/client/bar.js
build/out/clientDebug/baz.js
```

and then I've got a war project, call it 'server' that I'm trying to include the above into the a few different directories by doing:

```
war {
    from files(project(':webclient').file('build/out/WEB-INF')) {
        into('xxx')
    }
    from files(project(':webclient').file('build/out/client')) {
        into('yyy')
    }
    from files(project(':webclient').file('build/out/clientDebug')) {
        into('zzz')
    }
}
```

...but that doesn't work. I end up with all the contents under zzz/ !  Am I doing something wrong? bug in gradle (1.0-m6, btw)?

Comment: try nesting `from`s inside the `into`s instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't digged deeper in the details, but the files() method seems to cause the problems here. The following workaround should do the trick for you:

```
war{     
    from (project(':shared').file('build/out/WEB-INF')) {    
        into('xxx')
    }
    from (project(':shared').file('build/out/client')) {
        into('yyy')
    }
    from (project(':shared').file('build/out/clientDebug')) {
        into('zzz')
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and thanks! And note that the parenthesis around the arg to 'from' matter, for some reason.  Clearly my understanding of groovy is lacking.