# META-INF/services in JAR with Gradle

Tags: java, plugins, jar, gradle

I wanted to build a plugin module that can be loaded with a [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). This requires adding a file to the `META-INF/services` directory, that is named after the service interface and that contains the qualifying path to the class that implements it. Then you can load these services by calling `ServiceLoader.load()`.

Here is an example:

Say we want to provide a plugin interface called `org.example.plugins.PluginService`. We then provide an implementation of this service in the class `org.example.plugins.impl.ExamplePlugin`.

If we want to have some sort of plugin mechanism, we could create a JAR file, that contains the implementation. This JAR file must also contain the file `META-INF/services/org.example.plugins.PluginService`. This file must contain one line

```
org.example.plugins.impl.ExamplePlugin
```

to enable the `ServiceLoader` to find the implementation. If that JAR file is in the build path, you can load the plugin by calling

```
Iterator<PluginService> it = ServiceLoader.load(PluginService.class).iterator();
```

That iterator will give you access too all plugins that are found by the `ServiceLoader`.

For some reason Gradle doesn't include files into the `META-INF` directory by default. Is there a way to let the resulting JAR contain such a file?

I already found the method [`metaInf`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html#metaInf%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) in class `Jar`. But I don't know groovy good enough to find the solution on my own.

Comment: Are you sure? Works fine for me. Where exactly do you place this file and how do your `build.gradle` look?

Comment: There's a `META-INF` directory in the main source folder `src/main/java`. There's nothing special with the build script. It's almost a standard one, containing some additional dependencies and some custom repositories.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You place `META-INF/services/org.example.plugins.PluginService` in `src/main/java`, but it's not a source, it's a resource file, therefore it should be placed in resources folder according to Maven directory layout convention, that is

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.example.plugins.PluginService
```

In this case everything should work out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

Meanwhile I found a solution to my problem in a (somewhat) [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683375/how-do-i-add-a-properties-file-into-my-war-using-gradle).

Adding the following to the `gradle.build` file, resolves my problem

```
jar {
  from ('./src/main/java') {
    include 'META-INF/services/org.example.plugins.PluginService'
  }
}
```

Now the JAR file looks as expected

```
.
|- org
|  `- example
|     `- plugins
|        `- impl
|           `- ExamplePlugin.class
`- META-INF
   |- MANIFEST.MF
   `- services
      `- org.example.plugins.PluginService
```

Comment: I won't accept my own answer for now, because I think it's only a workaround. Like @axtavt stated above, it should work without these lines in the `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to inherit some ant based legacy code that does not follow the maven conventions, the following may help.

Define your source sets to match the legacy structure, and include a line like this:

`include 'META-INF/services/**'`

In your source sets.  This pattern is generic and will pick up all your meta inf services.

Full example below.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude '**/Test*.java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
            include '**/*.xml'
            include 'META-INF/services/**'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            include '**/Test*.java'

        }
        resources { srcDir 'resources' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Can try this: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.harbby.gradle.serviceloader

Usage

```
serviceLoader {
    serviceInterface 'org.example.plugins.PluginService'
    serviceInterface 'org.example.plugins.PluginService2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully they will implement this in the jar task just like ant does. Somebody already worked on it: http://fgaliegue.blogspot.fr/2013/06/gradle-serviceloader-support.html