# Copy META-INF files to jar in gradle

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I have a META-INF folder where the persitence.xml and orm.xml are located. When I build a jar file with following gradle those files are not getting included in the jar. How can i copy those files to the jar ?

Project structure

```
 src
 |
  - main(java/classes)
  - MET-INF(peristenc.xml, orm.xml)
```

Jar file code

```
jar {
    from {
     configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
     }
     {
      exclude "license/*.txt"
     }
}
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

Add your files under your project-directory/src/main/resources/META-INF/your-dir-or-files and they should be picked up and added to the jar.

see [META-INF/services in JAR with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254620/meta-inf-services-in-jar-with-gradle)