# Annotation Processors generated resources not packaged to APK

Tags: android, gradle, annotations, meta-inf

I've custom annotation processor generating factory classes and `META-INF/services/factory.interface.class` resource.

Annotation processor is used in library project and all generated files are packaged correctly into AAR.

When I use annotation processor in application project with library added as a dependency only classes from libraries `META-INF/services/factory.interface.class` exist in `APK/META-INF/services/factory.interface.class`

After some investigation I realized that `MergeJavaResourcesTransform` in android-gradle-plugin-1.5.0 (and 2.0.0-alpha3) looks for resources for merging in all `exploded-aar`s, `jar`s, and `intermediates/sourceFolderJavaResources`

Is there any way to merge `META-INF` from `intermediates/classes` (it's where resource files from annotation processor get created) or make annotation processor create file in `sourceFolderJavaResources`?

Only workaround I've found so far is to add `CopyTask` in application's buildscript

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  def variantName = variant.name
  def variantNameCapitalized = variantName.capitalize()
  def copyMetaInf = tasks.create "copyMetaInf$variantNameCapitalized", Copy
  copyMetaInf.from project.fileTree(javaCompile.destinationDir)
  copyMetaInf.include "META-INF/**"
  copyMetaInf.into "build/intermediates/sourceFolderJavaResources/$variantName"
  tasks.findByName("transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResFor$variantNameCapitalized").dependsOn copyMetaInf
}
```

But I do not wat to force compiler an library users do do anything more than adding dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is related to META-INF folder. Here is the bug reported for [Service Loader and META-INF](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59658)

By the way, there is a confirmed [solution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59658#c22):

- right click on /src/main (where you have /java and /res folders),
- select New > Folder > Java Resources Folder,
- click Finish (do not change Folder Location),
- right click on new /resources folder,
- select New > Directory
- enter "META-INF" (without quotes),
- right click on /resources/META-INF folder,
- select New > Directory
- enter "services" (without quotes)
- copy any file you need into /resources/META-INF/services

Also, you may want to check the following questions on SO:

- [META-INF/services in JAR with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254620/meta-inf-services-in-jar-with-gradle)
- [Using serviceloader on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760607/using-serviceloader-on-android)

---

Initial Answer:

You might want to try to configure your [library source set](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html#com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet)'s [`resources`](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html#com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet:resources) attribute (with your location of META-INF/services) which is responsible for:

> The Java resources which are to be copied into the javaResources
>   output directory.

Here is an example:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.srcDirs = ['/src/META_INF_generated']
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Library META-INF is correctly packaged to aar, there is a problem with MET-INF files in application.
adding `resources.srcDirs 'intermediates/classes/debug/META-INF'` doesn't help

Comment: @skyman I updated with extra details. There are some workarounds for the issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not work with build system. META-INF is generated in compile time both in library and application so coping apter compile but before packageing is not a solution

Comment: did you try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254620/meta-inf-services-in-jar-with-gradle ?

Comment: META-INF in correctly generated in annotation procesor and placed in jar (and then aar) when building a library project. It is also correctly created (and merged with INE from library) in application project but not taken into account when creatin result jar.